# Look and change data on mysql with PHP and strotime() function

Tags: php, mysql, function, datetime, pdo

I have a problem about strotime() function.

My code like below; (PHP PDO MySQL)

```
$BasketLastDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+7 minutes'));
$BasketLastDate = strtotime($BasketLastDate);
$sepetONAY = 0;
$sg = "SELECT * FROM baskets WHERE approve=1 and checkout=0";
foreach($db->query($sg) as $basketDetails){
$BasketDate = $basketDetails['basket_date'];
$BasketDate = strtotime($BasketDate);
// If the basket older than 7 minutes 
if ($BasketLastDate < $BasketDate){
 // code....
}
```

The code should look all rows and change situation if the record older than 7 minutes. But it doesn't happened.

Please help me guys.

Comment: why don't u use mysql datetime functions instead? `UPDATE table set column = value where datetimecolumn <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 MINUTE));` instead of the long php ifs?

Comment: What is the date format type of the mysql field?

Comment: My time format is YYYY-MM-DD HR:MN:SC TIMESTAMP

Comment: Actually, i couldn't do on mysql panel.

Comment: I try something like that; `CREATE EVENT sepetbosalt 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO 
UPDATE sepet SET onay = 0 
WHERE starih < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 MINUTE) && odeme = 0;;` But, anything didn't happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check time before 7 minutes not after :

```
$BasketLastDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-7 minutes'));
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it didn't work. When the take BasketLastDate(-7), BasketDate already older than 7 minutes. So, basket approve automatically change to negative. I want to check basket's creating time. If the basket older than 7 minutes, change the situation.

Comment: i think you can check do something like that on condition current time - baskettime > 7

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when change the date format to strtotime format, date looks like 32124123123. So, > 7 is not avaliable, not a valid value. But I cannot understand, why the strtotime format doesn't work.